# My program doesn't allow me to ask for user input inside a constructor

Tags: java, methods, constructor

I am creating a bunch of methods and constructors for a digital clock, and I am trying to make one where the user inputs everything in  but the program is not allowing me to ask for user input.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

 import java.util.Calendar;

 public class DigitalClock {

 Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

 int hour = 0;

 int minute = 0;

 boolean am = true;


 public DigitalClock() {
    hour = 12;
    minute = 0;
    am = true;
 }

 public void setTime() {
hour = input.nextInt();
minute = input.nextInt();

}
public void getHour() {
hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY); 
}

public void getMinute() {
minute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
}

public void isMorning() {
if(hour > 12){
am = false;
}else{
am = true;
}


}




}
```

Comment: And why is it not allowing you to do this?

Comment: You’ve asked 9 questions but never accepted anyone’s answer. For shame.

Comment: Where is your main method?

Comment: Why would you create a constructor that accepts user input? It is supposed to be a class definition, whatever you parse from the command line can be passed as a parameter to a constructor. You should read about MVC programming, your clock is a model, when you are dealing with the command line and parsing it that is the view, ideally a controller should take the information from the view, call a method(s) to update your model which is the clock. Here is a link to the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model–view–controller) on MVC.

Answer (score 0):

```
Scanner object is not used. Main method is missing as well.

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); needs to be added. Add a println to ask for inputs.

example: 

Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);  // Read from System.in
System.out.println("Enter the Hour: ");
hour = input.nextInt(); // Scans the input as an int.

input.close();
```